# TLE Error to Remove element from LinkedList

Tags: python, linked-list

I am working on an easy LinkedList basic operation problem on [Remove Linked List Elements - LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/problems/remove-linked-list-elements/)

> 203. Remove Linked List Elements
>
> Remove all elements from a linked list of integers that have value **val**.
>
> **Example:**
>
> ```
> Input:  1->2->6->3->4->5->6, val = 6
> Output: 1->2->3->4->5
> ```

My solution:

> The 3 nodes: prev_node(prev), current_node(cur), next_node(nxt)
>
> change `prev.next` from current_node to next_node
>
> prev
>
> cur = prev.next
>
> nxt = prev.next.next

```py
# Definition for singly-linked list.
# class ListNode:
#     def __init__(self, x):
#         self.val = x
#         self.next = None

class Solution:
    def removeElements(self, head: ListNode, val: int) -> ListNode:
        #relation: prev.next = nxt to replace cur
        prev = head
        if prev == None: return head
        if prev.next == None: #cur == None:
            if prev.next.val == 6:
                prev.next = None
            return head 

        while prev.next != None: #cur !=None
            if prev.next.val == 6: #if cur.val == 6
                nxt = prev.next.next
                prev.next = nxt
                prev = prev.next #advance to traverse
        return head
```

However, it reported `Time Limit Exceeded`Error.

I assume that problem is not  performance but mistakes in my implementation which I don't find.

What's the problem?

Comment: Yes, on the leetcodes problem link [Remove Linked List Elements - LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/problems/remove-linked-list-elements/) @Prune

Comment: Your posted code is missing a test driver that would illustrate the problem.  As it is, I don't see how your `removeElements` method is supposed to work, as there is no `ListNode` defintion.  Most of all, the method appears to ignore the input parameter `val` -- rather, it is hard-coded to remove the value `6`, regardless of the calling sequence.

Comment: Links to external code are not generally acceptable.  Please refer to the posting guidelines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's more than one errors in your implementations, the key is that your solution did not advance if `prev.next.val != val`.

A hint: Use dummy to simplify the process.

```
class Solution:
    def removeElements(self, head: ListNode, val: int) -> ListNode:
        #relation: prev.next = nxt to replace cur
        dummy = prev = ListNode(0)
        prev.next = head 

        while prev != None and prev.next != None: #cur !=None
            if prev.next.val == val: #if cur.val == val
                nxt = prev.next.next
                prev.next = nxt
            else:
                prev = prev.next #advance to traverse
        return dummy.next
```